# Break a string with optional space and number and a dot

Tags: php, regex

trying to break a string from (optional space) number and a dot.

```
$string = "1.1Kumar/Sandeep MR*T0148.4801 12.23Pal/Sandeep MR*T643.948";
$regex1 = "/(\s*[0-9]+\.)/";
$regex2 = "/(?<=\s)[0-9]+\./";
```

I need to break from **1.** and **12.** .
The first regex gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 1Kumar/Sandeep MR*T
    [2] => 4801
    [3] => 23Pal/Sandeep MR*T
    [4] => 948
)
```

The second regex gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.1Kumar/Sandeep MR*T0148.4801 
    [1] => 23Pal/Sandeep MR*T643.948
)
```

I am trying to get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1Kumar/Sandeep MR*T0148.4801 
    [1] => 23Pal/Sandeep MR*T643.948
)
```

Comment: How about [this demo](https://eval.in/602339).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you example string this will work:

```
\b\d+\.
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/faiCXdkSQyvyjE4U)

It makes sure there's a *word break* before the numeric part. (start of line or a space does it)

Comment: I did not read the other part, so your's is definately better :)

Comment: The regex result is not what i was looking for when string is "1.1Kumar/Sandeep MR*0148.4801"

Comment: You could go with my first *fiddle*: `(?:^|\s)\d+\.`. That'll work in both cases.